# Wordpress Membership Plugin Conditional Statement

Tags: php, wordpress

I have plugin by WPMU that creates a membership system for your wordpress theme. Im trying to make it display a gallery only when a user is a premium member and Im completely lost. My code basicly grabs part of the url and pastes it into variables in my susbscription div to draw the information needed. I need it to check if the user is logged in but Im not sure how to do that. Here is my code, Thanks:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = rtrim($url, '/');

function drawId($url) {
    return array_pop(explode('-', $url));
}
?>

<div class="main-container col2-right-layout">

    <div class="main">
    <p><?php echo drawId($url); ?></p>
    <?php get_template_part('loop');?>

    <div id="subscription">
    <p><?php echo nggcf_get_gallery_field(drawId($url), "Gallery Text"); /* where 1 is the gallery id */ ?></p>
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[nggallery id='.drawId($url).']');?>
    </div>
    </div><!-- .main -->
</div><!-- .main-container col2-right-layout -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The following is copied and pasted from [the plugin's support forms](http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/conditionals-for-member-levels):**

you can try any of the following for your customization needs:

current_user_is_member()

current_user_on_level($level_id)

current_user_on_subscription($sub_id)

And of course, you can get the level_id and sub_id from the respective membership level and subscription lists.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check if a user is logged in, in wordpress, it is just a condition like this:

```
if(is_user_logged_in()){
     //do you stuff
}
```

hope this help. read more [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)

Comment: Thanks @bingjie2680! I had tried something like that but Im trying to look into the plugin files now and see how it determines when a user is a member or not. Any suggestions on how I could find it faster?

Comment: can you please elaborate what a member is? a subsrciber, contributor or something else

Comment: Well this is the plugin http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/membership , it basicly sets up a blog to support different levels of memberships that are paid for. The site I'm building is supposed to have a certain area displayed for anyone who visits the site, and another area is supposed to be reserved for members only.

Comment: hi, Carlos, in this case, I am not able to help you since I don't know this plugin. maybe try their support forum or something.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin allows only people that are logged in to your site to use the site:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/private-wp/

Maybe by creating memberships though your admin panel you could target the the user in that way.

Comment: Thanks but I'm kinda stuck using the plugin I have now... (boss' orders) hah and the reason for it is because It supports a paid feature for paypal. It has to be used to generate revenue for our client